# Java Package with hyphen in name

Tags: java, import

How do I import a package named "poof-support" .

No, I can't change the package name,
I'm getting an: error '.' expected .
The line giving the error is:

```
import poof-support.exception;
```

Comment: If you have _package named "poof-support"_, that means you had a declaration `package poof-support;`. I'd like to see how you compiled that.

Comment: (for reference, this was in my early days of coding, and most likely, yes I was misusing the packages, and poorly handling their name, I changed the accepted answer, thanks everyone)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't have `-` in your package name. So you will need to change the name.

#### Some Package Naming Conventions from java Documentation

- Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces.
- In some cases, the internet domain name may not be a valid package name. This can occur if the domain name contains a hyphen or other special character, if the package name begins with a digit or other character that is illegal to use as the beginning of a Java name, or if the package name contains a reserved Java keyword, such as "int". In this event, the suggested convention is to add an underscore. For example:

> ```
>   incorrect names                | correct names
>   ---------------------------------------------------------  
>   hyphenated-name.example.org    | org.example.hyphenated_name
>   example.int                    | int_.example
>   123name.example.com            | com.example._123name
> ```

check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) for naming conventions of package.

Answer (score 8):

You will *have* to change its name, since it's illegal to use a dash in a package name. The recommendation is to use an underscore instead.